# The Unix password for msysgit

Tags: msysgit

I have download and install msysgit 1.7.6 from 
http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/ on Windows XP.

But when I try to use git to clone a git repository, it asks me for my 'Local Unix Password'.

Can you please tell me what is my 'local unix password' for msysgit?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't ask for a "local" unix password unless you are cloning a git repo with a protocol needing an authentication, like ssh or https. See [Git protocols](http://progit.org/book/ch4-1.html)

This is usually the case (i.e it will ask you for a password), for:

- ssh protocol, if it cannot find the right public/private key (it falls back to user account authentication)
- http protocol, is the remote http server is configured with a file or ldap authentication in the virtual directory of its config.